# cannot set a powerline font for the terminal inside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, powerline

I was trying to set my terminal inside Visual Studio 2019 like the one I have in the Windows Terminal and Visual Studio Code, but I cannot set a powerline font like Cascadia Code PL in the menu. It's me or it's not yet supported?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Cascade Code font via Chocolaty.
It did the trick for me for VScode AND Powershell/CMD Terminal.
Maybe it does the trick for Visual Studio 2019 as well.
It workes with the Community edition.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more convenient to install with package manager like Chocolatey

> choco install cascadiacodepl

[cascadiacodepl](https://chocolatey.org/packages/cascadiacodepl)

At home it works with Windows Terminal, Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. **It seems the Terminal only supports TTF fonts.**

After you download [Cascadia Code from Github](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/releases) make sure to install Cascadia Mono PL from the ttf folder! Also don't forget to restart Visual Studio so that the font properly loads.